# Изменение позиционирования элементов в Grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Можно ли реализовать средствами Bootstrap Grid компоновку, которая бы на компьютерах имела вид:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А на мобильных устройствах выглядела бы вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрю в сторону `col-sm-push-*`, `col-sm-pull-*`, но решение не приходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull-Push тут вряд ли поможет, а вот hidden-visible - вполне:

```css
[class^="col"] {
  padding: 5px !important;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.inner {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.image {
  height: 150px;
}

.text {
  height: 105px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .image {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
<div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-8">
     <div class="inner header">Header</div>
     <div class="inner image visible-sm visible-xs">Image</div>
     <div class="inner text">text</div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
     <div class="inner image">Image</div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```